# Print a x,y matrix, java

Tags: java, matrix, for-loop

I want to print the followin matrix using for loops:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6
 2 3 4 5 6 1
 3 4 5 6 1 2
 4 5 6 1 2 3
 5 6 1 2 3 4
 6 1 2 3 4 5
```

I use:

```
public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {
    for(int w = 1; w <= 6; w++){
        System.out.println("");
        for(int p = w; p <= 6; p++){
            System.out.print(p + "");
        }
    }
}
```

But it prints:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6
 2 3 4 5 6
 3 4 5 6
 4 5 6
 5 6
 6
```

Comment: Look at all of the different ways people came up with to fix this code. Kinda reminds me of the games people play when they're trying to overthink FizzBuzz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your inner loop to this:

```
for (int p = w; p <= 6 + w; p++) {
    System.out.print((p - 1) % 6 + 1 + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is easier to work with modulo to print every possible combination. But, this returns a number between 0 and 5, so you have to add 1.

```
final int SIZE = 6;
for(int w = 0; w < SIZE; w++) {
  for(int p = 0; p < SIZE; p++) {
    System.out.print(((w + p) % SIZE) + 1);
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {
    for(int w = 0; w < 6; w++){
        System.out.println("");
        for(int p = 0; p < 6; p++){
                System.out.print((p + w) % 6 + 1  + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, `p = w` is fine; you just need to adjust for it a different way.

Comment: Lol I totally misunderstood the question at first. Now that I got it, I've edited >.<

Answer (score 2):

This should help you out. Almost what you are trying to do, but with an extra for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int w = 1; w <= 6; w++) {
            System.out.println("");

            for (int p = w; p <= 6; p++) {
                System.out.print(p + "");
            }
            for (int q = 1; q < w; q++) {
                System.out.print(q + "");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That doesn't give the same output. The numbers in the lower half should also be increasing.

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because your inner loop depends on w, but w is incrementing.

edit -- here is what i came up with

```
public class Loop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int w = 1; w <= 6; w++) {
            System.out.println("");
            Loop.printRow(w);

        }
    }

    public static void printRow(int startAt) {

        int p = startAt;
        for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++, p++){
            if (p > 6) p -= 6;

            System.out.print(p + "");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work, although I haven't tested it!:

```
for(int w = 1; w <= 6; w++){ 
    System.out.println("");
    for(int p = 0; p <= 5; p++){
       if((w+p) <=6) {
           System.out.print((w+p) + "");
       } else {
           System.out.print((w+p-6) + "");
       }
    } 
}
```

Cheers

Comment: It needs a `% 6` somewhere to make the numbers wrap back to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have given fancy solutions with modulo, but I think the simplest thing is to have a second inner loop that covers the numbers the first inner loop missed.

```
public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {
    for(int w = 1; w <= 6; w++){
        for(int p = w; p <= 6; p++){
            System.out.print(p + "");
        }
        for(int p = 1; p < w; p++){
            System.out.print(p + "");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```