# How to print a board in Java for Conway's Game Of Life

Tags: java, boolean, conways-game-of-life

Ok, so my homework question is on Conway's Game Of Life. I'm not the best programmer so I'm having trouble with this one. We don't have to create an actual animation; just print to the console.

The first method of the question is to print the board.

A board is represented as a 2-dimensional boolean array:

```
boolean[][] board = new boolean[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
```

Your print method is called as follows:

```
public static void printBoard(boolean[][] board)
```

The method should print each row of the array on separate lines with a ‘.’ representing a false cell and a ‘*’ representing true.

I know that a boolean means its either false or true but I'm not sure how to do this. Should I use a while loop?

```
public static void printBoard(boolean[][] board) {
   boolean[][] board = new boolean[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

   while (i < numberofColumns) {
        System.out.print(".");
        i++;
    }

    >while (i < numberofColumns) {
        System.out.print("*");
        j++;

    }

    System.out.println(); }
```

So that is what I have now. Am I even close? I'm getting the error message 'board is already defined in printBoard(boolean[][])

Sorry if the question is unclear.

Comment: Use two nested `for()` loops to draw your board.

Comment: Question is most likely answered multiple times already. Try to search for "print matrix". For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980832/print-a-x-y-matrix-java

Comment: @Peter Lijenberg - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag

Comment: Can anyone else offer advice? I've updated the question.

Comment: Do you own homework without cheating. You're more likely to learn things that way. And know that your lecturers also use the internet and know how to use Google.

Comment: Please an answer as an answer to your question and upvote if it helped you. It is the least you can do when somebody invests time in helping you out. You have asked six questions and received answers to them all, but never  accepted one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want to do is iterate over the entire array of arrays. You should use one `for` loop to iterate over `board` (or a foreach loop), and then another `for` loop embedded within the first one to iterate over each array of `board`. In this embedded loop, you can simply do something like `System.out.print(board[i][j] ? "*" : ".")`. At the end of the first for loop, you will want to print a new line so as to obtain the rectangular format.